# Select default value OrderType selector by user login on SOOrder Screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

On SOOrder Screen: I have OrderType: C1,C2,CS,SO and C1->userRole A, C2->userRole B,CS & SO->userRole Administrator. I want to select the default Ordertype by userlogin, if userlogin= Admin so show the selector are CS & SO.
This is the my Code Editor: SOOrderEntry (Sales Orders):

```
 protected void SOOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{

  PXResult<PX.SM.UsersInRoles> user = PXSelect<PX.SM.UsersInRoles,
                               Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>.Select(Base);
  if(user != null)
  {
    PX.SM.UsersInRoles role = user;
    if(role.Rolename == "Administrator")
      e.NewValue = "CS";
    else
      if(role.Rolename == "A")
        e.NewValue = "C1";
      if(role.Rolename == "B")
        e.NewValue = "C2";
  }
}
```

My result is: when login us role Administrator, it showed all the order type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

```
    public class CustomOrderTypeSelectorAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
    {
        public CustomOrderTypeSelectorAttribute()
            : base(typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable GetRecords()
        {
            PXResult<PX.SM.UsersInRoles> user = PXSelect<PX.SM.UsersInRoles,
                Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>.Select(Base);
            if(user != null)
            {

                PXResult<SOOrderType> orderTypes = null;
                if(roleName == "Administrator")
                {
                    orderTypes = PXSelect<SOOrderType,
                        Where<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrderType.orderType>>,
                            Or<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrderType.orderType>>>>>.Select(Base, "CS", "SO");
                }
                else if(roleName == "A")
                {
                    orderTypes = PXSelect<SOOrderType,
                        Where<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrderType.orderType>>>>.Select(Base, "C1");
                }
                else if(role.Rolename == "B")
                {
                    orderTypes = PXSelect<SOOrderType,
                        Where<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrderType.orderType>>>>.Select(Base, "C2");
                }

                foreach (var item in orderTypes)
                    yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then use cache attached to override OrderType property with custom select above

Comment: @Đinh, I'm junior so could you tell me how I put your coding?

Comment: @Hybridzz, what's constructor ?

Comment: @Hybridzz, pls help me this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408210/acumatica-sql-view-based-on-row-level-security?noredirect=1#comment64245161_38408210

Comment: @meimei, you should ask some questions to google even if you are junior. did you try the above attribute?